# Pyspark Groupby and Count a string within array

Tags: python, group-by, count, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that is reading from Twitter JSON file.

I am trying to find the count of all URLs in my dataset. The URLs are stored in an array of strings. So, some objects have 1 URL and some have multiple as shown in the following:
[image]

How can I count the occurrences of the URLs within each and every array and get the output showing the count for every URL that is stored in these arrays?

I am using the following but it is not showing me the desired result:

```
print(withURLenglish.groupby('entities.urls.expanded_url').count().sort(desc('count')).show(n=1500,truncate=False))
```

'entities.urls.expanded_url' returns a column that is an array of strings

my dataframe is defined in the following variable:

```
data = df.na.drop(subset=["user.id"]).select(["user","text","entities", "lang"])
withURLenglish = data.filter(size(data['entities.urls']) > 0).filter(data['lang']=='en').select(["user","text","entities", "lang"])
```

and the schema is as follow:
[image]

```
print(withURLenglish.head())
```

will produce:

> Row(user=Row(contributors_enabled=False, created_at='Mon Sep 22
>   20:19:17 +0000 2008', default_profile=False,
>   default_profile_image=False, description='My tweets are like ziti.',
>   favourites_count=605, follow_request_sent=None, followers_count=518,
>   following=None, friends_count=495, geo_enabled=True, id=16409225,
>   id_str='16409225', is_translator=False, lang='en', listed_count=17,
>   location='Same City', name='bojack horton ', notifications=None,
>   profile_background_color='FFFFFF',
>   profile_background_image_url='http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/502679497120837632/BxqZlfVD.jpeg',
>   profile_background_image_url_https='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/502679497120837632/BxqZlfVD.jpeg',
>   profile_background_tile=True,
>   profile_banner_url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/16409225/1398568361',
>   profile_image_url='http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/509891854360264704/R9q_xrfd_normal.jpeg',
>   profile_image_url_https='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/509891854360264704/R9q_xrfd_normal.jpeg',
>   profile_link_color='121444', profile_sidebar_border_color='FFFFFF',
>   profile_sidebar_fill_color='FAFEFF', profile_text_color='243536',
>   profile_use_background_image=False, protected=False,
>   screen_name='aehorton', statuses_count=43978, time_zone='Eastern Time
>   (US & Canada)', url='http://wtfismikewearing.tumblr.com/',
>   utc_offset=-18000, verified=False), text='RT @ComplexMag: Radio
>   stations switching to only classic hip-hop are seeing increased
>   ratings. http://tgegregergeg.co/Fn81nNs68R http://tssdfsfsf.co/UvBQ4MDbu9',
>   entities=Row(hashtags=[], media=None, symbols=[], trends=[],
>   urls=[Row(display_url='trib.al/htg6YTP',
>   expanded_url='http://trib.al/htg6YTP', indices=[95, 117],
>   url='http://tregregergge.co/Fn81nNs68R'),
>   Row(display_url='pic.twitter.com/UvBQ4MDbu9',
>   expanded_url='http://twitter.com/ComplexMag/status/549700671382233088/photo/1',
>   indices=[118, 140], url='http://tsdfsfdsf.co/UvBQ4MDbu9')],
>   user_mentions=[Row(id=13049362, id_str='13049362', indices=[3, 14],
>   name='Complex ', screen_name='ComplexMag')]), lang='en')

Any ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: please give us a sample dataframe that you are working on. thanks.

Comment: Hi , please see the updated post above. Is that what you meant?